# Accumulating lists in Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

Say I have a `pl.DataFrame()` with 2 columns: The first column contains `Date`, the second `List[str]`.

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame([
    pl.Series('Date', [2000, 2001, 2002]),
    pl.Series('Ids', [
        ['a'], 
        ['b', 'c'], 
        ['d'], 
    ])
])
```

| Date | Ids |
| --- | --- |
| 2000 | `['a']` |
| 2001 | `['b', 'c']` |
| 2002 | `['d']` |

Is it possible to accumulate the `List[str]` column so that each row contains itself and all previous lists in Polars? Like so:

| Date | Ids |
| --- | --- |
| 2000 | `['a']` |
| 2001 | `['a', 'b', 'c']` |
| 2002 | `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a [rolling groupby](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/howcani/timeseries/temporal_groupby.html#grouping-by-rolling-windows-with-groupby_rolling)?

```
(df.groupby_rolling(index_column="Date", period=f"{df.height}i")
   .agg(pl.col("Ids").flatten()))
```

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌──────┬─────────────────────┐
│ Date | Ids                 │
│ ---  | ---                 │
│ i64  | list[str]           │
╞══════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 2000 | ["a"]               │
│ 2001 | ["a", "b", "c"]     │
│ 2002 | ["a", "b", ... "d"] │
└──────┴─────────────────────┘
```

---

The `index_column` is not particularly relevant for your use-case, we're just using `Date` here as it is an `int`.

Instead, a common approach is to add a "row count" column to use.

It needs to be cast in order to be used with `.groupby_rolling`

```
(df.with_row_count()
   .with_columns(pl.col("row_nr").cast(pl.Int64))
   .groupby_rolling(index_column="row_nr", period=f"{df.height}i")
   .agg(pl.exclude("row_nr")))
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌────────┬────────────────────┬────────────────────────────┐
│ row_nr | Date               | Ids                        │
│ ---    | ---                | ---                        │
│ i64    | list[i64]          | list[list[str]]            │
╞════════╪════════════════════╪════════════════════════════╡
│ 0      | [2000]             | [["a"]]                    │
│ 1      | [2000, 2001]       | [["a"], ["b", "c"]]        │
│ 2      | [2000, 2001, 2002] | [["a"], ["b", "c"], ["d"]] │
└────────┴────────────────────┴────────────────────────────┘
```

You can use `.last()` on columns where you want only the original value:

```
(df.with_row_count()
   .with_columns(pl.col("row_nr").cast(pl.Int64))
   .groupby_rolling(index_column="row_nr", period=f"{df.height}i")
   .agg(pl.col("Date").last(), pl.col("Ids").flatten()))
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌────────┬──────┬─────────────────────┐
│ row_nr | Date | Ids                 │
│ ---    | ---  | ---                 │
│ i64    | i64  | list[str]           │
╞════════╪══════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 0      | 2000 | ["a"]               │
│ 1      | 2001 | ["a", "b", "c"]     │
│ 2      | 2002 | ["a", "b", ... "d"] │
└────────┴──────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Using `.arange()` is another way to get a "row count" - it produces an `int` which allows skipping the `.cast` - which some prefer.

```
(df.with_columns(row_nr = pl.arange(0, pl.count()))
   .groupby_rolling(index_column="row_nr", period=f"{df.height}i")
   .agg(pl.col("Date").last(), pl.col("Ids").flatten()))
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌────────┬──────┬─────────────────────┐
│ row_nr | Date | Ids                 │
│ ---    | ---  | ---                 │
│ i64    | i64  | list[str]           │
╞════════╪══════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 0      | 2000 | ["a"]               │
│ 1      | 2001 | ["a", "b", "c"]     │
│ 2      | 2002 | ["a", "b", ... "d"] │
└────────┴──────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have so far:

```
(
    df.select([
        pl.col('Date'),
        pl.col('Doi').cumulative_eval(pl.element().list()).arr.eval(pl.element().flatten())
    ])
)
```

If anyone has something better, I'll give them the answer.

Comment: @jqurious Thank you for your answer! 
This works perfectly if my `Date` column is an `int`, but no longer works if I change the dtype to `Date`. 
Would it be possible for you to edit your question to account for this?

Comment: You can create a "dummy" int column to use as the index, e.g. `.with_row_count()` or `df.with_columns(idx = 1).groupby_rolling(index_column="idx", ...`

Comment: I've added an explanation regarding `index_column` - hope that helps.

Comment: @jqurious I really appreciate you! And I'm sure others will as well!